# Execute Remote Perl Script on a Windows Box from a Linux Box

Tags: linux, perl, ssh, execute, shellexecute

We recently got SSH setup on our Windows boxes so we could eliminate the need for disc mounts on our Linux machines. We are using Pentaho and I am writing a shell script that will, from a Linux box, SSH into the Windows box and execute a perl script.

I have able to write in a way to SSH into the windows box and switch to the directory that holds the Perl scripts that I need to execute, I just can't figure out how to actually execute them.

This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh -t xxxxx@xxxxx "cd /path/to/script/ /path/to/perl.exe HelloWorld.pl"
```

I have also tried:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh -t xxxxx@xxxxx "cd /path/to/directory/with/perl/script" \
                   "/path/to/perl.exe HelloWorld.pl"
```

Both attempts result in a short delay and then a "disconnected from xxxxx" and the perl does not run. I can do all of these steps manually through a shell, but can't seem to get them working in script form. As a note, the only way I've been able to execute the perl scripts is if have the shell **in** the directory the perl script is in.

Comment: Do you really need to change to that directory before calling your perl script?

Comment: It appears so, when I attempted to run it earlier from the shell without changing to the directory that the perl script was located (say I just did /path/to/perl.exe /path/to/perl/script.pl) I would get "Perl Script Not Found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use either a semi colon to end your statements, or execute with one statement.
try the following:

```
ssh xxxxx@xxxxx "cd /path/to/script/; /path/to/perl.exe HelloWorld.pl"
```

or:

```
ssh xxxxx@xxxxx "/path/to/perl.exe /path/to/script/HelloWorld.pl"
```

Comment: That worked! Excellent, thank you very much. You don't know it, but you just gave me the final piece in finishing up nearly a years worth of work.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it helped.  So that people know the question has been answered correctly, it would be great if you could mark it as so.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I wasn't 100% familiar with the site. You should be marked now.

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows command shell, you can use `&&` like in a Unix-shell. If you expect the first command to succeed,

```
ssh -t xxxxx@xxxxx "cd /path/to/script/ && /path/to/perl.exe HelloWorld.pl"
```

will work.